# Wolfram|Cloud memory limit exceeded

Tags: memory, code-review, wolfram-cloud

I have some formulas from a paper ([Provably Manipulation-Resistant Reputation Systems](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v49/christiano16.pdf)) that I would like to run 3 times (with different nummbers).

Therefore, I wrote a small programm that now finally works ... and bam:

> This computation has exceeded the memory limit for your plan

I didn't know something like this could occur.

Is there anything I can do to improve my code so that it runs to completion?

Formulas:

[image: argmax]

[image: product]

This is my code (first time coding with Wolfram|Cloud):

```
unr =  4;
lnr =  3;
size = unr * lnr;
eps =  0.2;

e = SparseArray[{{2, 3} -> -1}, {size,size}];
n = Array[f , {size,size}];

bounds = (If[0 <= # <= 1, True, Throw[False], Throw[False]])&;
checkLessEquals = (Catch[Map[bounds, #, {2}]; Throw[True]])&;

prod = (Total[#1*#2, 2])&;

ArgMax[
  {eps *  prod[e, n] + Log[Det[n+IdentityMatrix[size]]], 
   checkLessEquals[n] && PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[n]}, 
  Flatten[n]]
```

Comment: "from a paper" - for reference, could you link to it, please?

Comment: @J.M. Sure. Sorry, i forgot to reference it.

Comment: Does it make sense to get that `Det[]`? Note that you should be able to work out for yourself what the Determinant is with relative ease! It's a lot of work, but this is what hangs your calculation.

Comment: @Feyre: I can't exclude Det[] from the calculation because i'm trying to find a matrix (n) that maximises the complete formula. I thought it's more likely that the computation is so bad because i have 144 variables that i'm ajusting to find a maximum for the calculation. I'm not sure if the constraints / bounds i specified is correct this way.. because that should minimalize the computation.

Comment: You've got other problems though `checkLessEquals[n]` and `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[n]` both evaluate to `False`.

Comment: @Feyre: That is what i meant. I'm not sure if i specified the constraints corretly. All variables in the matrix n should ne between 0 and 1 and the matrix should be positiv semi-definite.

Comment: For that, you could do `0 < # < 1 & /@ Flatten@n` for the first. You could also explicitly test for the other one.

Comment: Scale your problem down to 4 variables, perhaps even 3 variables and verify each step works. Also eps* prod[e,n] seems to just be -eps* f[2,3]. Also your Throw and Catch seem like they can just be reduced to returning True or False. Demonstrate the working 4 variable problem and this should point out exactly why it fails when you increase the variables to 5, 6, 7, ...

Comment: I am confused about how this question relates to wolfram alpha, since the post clearly contains wolfram language code.  @besnep, how do you send this code to alpha?  Are you using a cloud notebook?

Comment: @Bill: The matrix e is changing (it's just static for this example). I don't know how you would reduce the throw/catch? Every value of the matrix needs to be between the bounds 0 and 1.

Comment: @JasonB.: I probably don't know the difference but i changed the question to Wolfram|Cloud since i'm talking about programming with it.

Comment: My solution was not to use Wolfram|Cloud. Matlab wasn't any help either. Finally i did a gradient implementation in java and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the conditions explicitly:

```
ve = Array[v, {size}];
ArgMax[{(eps*prod[e, n] + Log[Det[n + IdentityMatrix[size]]]), 
0 < # < 1 & /@ Flatten@n, ({ve}.n.ve) > 0}, Flatten[{n, ve}]]
Chop[%, 10^-8]
```

> `1., 0, 1., 1., 0, 0, 1., 1., 0, 1., 1., 0, 0, 1., 1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
>   1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0, 1., 0, 1., 1., 1., 1., 0, 0, 0, 1., 1.4288, 
>   0.403799, -0.37193, 0.742415, -0.39883, -0.0280605}`